# Multiple schedular thread submit tasks RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, executorservice

In my application, I have multiple `scheduler` threads that create tasks. For example **each** scheduler threads can create bunch of tasks :

```
TaskCreator tastCreator;
for (Report report: report) {
     taskCreator.createTask(report);
}
```

The scheduler threads can run concurrently as you can see from the logs:

```
15:57:20.107  INFO [    scheduler-4] c.task.ReportExportSchedulerTask   : Task created
15:57:20.107  INFO [    scheduler-2] c.task.ReportExportSchedulerTask   : Task created
```

I have a `TaskCreator` component as follows that passes the task to the `executeJob()`:

```
@Component
public class TaskCreator {
    @Autowired
    private SftpTaskExecutor sftpTaskExecutor;
    @Autowired
    SftpConfig sftpConfig;

    @Autowired
    private SFTPConnectionManager connectionManager;

    public void createTask(Report report) {
        sftpTaskExecutor.executeJob(new JobProcessorTask(...));
    }

    public void validateTasksExecution() {
        sftpTaskExecutor.getExecutorService().shutdown();
        while (!sftpTaskExecutor.getExecutorService().isTerminated()) ;
        connectionManager.disconnect();
    }
}
```

`SftpTaskExecutor` `Component` as follows that constructs an `executorService` to which I submit the above tasks to:

```
@Component
public class SftpTaskExecutor {
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void executeJob(JobProcessorTask jobProcessorTask) {
        executorService.execute(jobProcessorTask);
    }

    public ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        return executorService;
    }
}
```

My question is, if two or more **scheduler** threads are creating tasks and submitting to executor service concurrently, the above throws a `RejectedExecutionException` with one scheduler task not finished (i.e. file not sent)

For each **schedule** threads, I need to be able to call `validateTasksExecution()` without interfering with the other scheduler thread. In other words, not disconnect while other scheduler is still processing.

Am I using the `ExecutorService` correctly in this regard? How can I change the above to be thread safe?

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, if two or more scheduler threads are creating tasks and submitting to executor service concurrently, the above throws a RejectedExecutionException with one scheduler task not finished (i.e. file not sent)

Let's take a look at the [javadocs for `ExecutorService.execute(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable))

> `RejectedExecutionException` - if this task cannot be accepted for execution.

In looking at the `ThreadPoolExecutor` (and associated) code, the jobs get rejected for 2 reasons:

- The queue for the jobs is full (this doesn't apply to you because the queues are by default unbounded)
- The executor service is no longer running (ding ding ding)

I believe that your executor service has been shutdown, most likely because the first of your threads has called `validateTasksExecution()` before the 2nd thread calls `executeJob(...)`.  Your code is incorrect if you are trying to reuse that thread-pool.  That you are also closing the `connectionManager()` makes me wonder if you want to re-use the `SftpTaskExecutor` at all.

If you want each thread to see if its operation is done but have the thread-pool stay running then you need to be saving the [`Future`(s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) from the `ExecutorService.submit(...)` method and call `get()` on them.  That will tell you when the jobs are done.

Something like:

```
public Future<Void> createTask(Report report) {
    return sftpTaskExecutor.executeJob(new JobProcessorTask(...));
}

public void validateTasksExecution(Future<Void> future) {
    // there is some exceptions here you need to handle
    future.get();
}

public void shutdown() {
    sftpTaskExecutor.shutdown();
    connectionManager.disconnect();
}

...

public Future<Void> executeJob(JobProcessorTask jobProcessorTask) {
    return executorService.submit(jobProcessorTask);
}
```

If you need to monitor multiple jobs then you should store them in a collection and call `get()` on them serially although the jobs will be running in parallel.

The alternative would be for you to have a separate `ExecutorService` for each transaction which is wasteful but maybe not so bad considering that it is managing sftp calls.

> ```
> while (!sftpTaskExecutor.getExecutorService().isTerminated()) ;
> ```

Yeah you don't want to spin like that.  See [`awaitTermination(...)` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).